# Two charges in a medium where different permittivity is adjacent

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I was thinking about the following: Assuming that you have NON SPHERICALLY SYMMETRIC charges and they are both in medium 1. Does it make a difference(whereby I am referring to the total force) if there is a second medium 2 in the local area of both, such that both charges are NOT in the second medium, but very close to it to the case where only medium 1 is around them?